# Exim4 panicking, missing /etc/vmail/<domain>/passwd file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exim

I keep getting this error.

> /var/log/mail.err  Jan 22 05:00:03 home exim4: ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size, mail system possibly broken

Checking /var/log/exim4/paniclog, I see this.

> 2015-01-22 01:48:16 failed to expand condition "${if and{{bool_lax{NULL}}{bool_lax{${if eq  {}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/vmail/$domain/passwd}}}{no}{yes}}}}}}" for vmail_deliver router: failed to open /etc/vmail//passwd for linear search: No such file or directory inside "and{...}" condition

I can verify the file is not there. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, VPS with webuzo control panel, which prefers exim4.

Reading documentation and searching did not come up with anything. Now mail seems to be broken for that domain. Removing the paniclog, restarting exim4 as suggested in other errors does not help.

The error comes back after a day or so.

Edit: Forgot to mention that there is another domain on this vps too, does not produce this error, and does not have a passwd file too.

Comment: You have the doubled slash here `/etc/vmail//passwd`. That means that you have an empty variable `$domain` at the time. Look like the problem somewhere else, not with `passwd` file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was a typo on my behalf, trying to remove the domain name for privacy issue. I have to agree, the problem is somewhere else since there is another domain and does not have a passwd file, working with no problems.

Comment: So just create an empty file `/etc/vmail/domain/passwd` and see what happened.

Comment: The solution was adding a dummy/test user with some strong password (to prevent being abused), that added the file with the proper permissions and the content that exim expects. It seems that exim expects at least one local user. That domain had all forwarding.
Thanks, you gave a starting point where to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: After Kondybas suggesting adding a blank passwd file, I added a new user, and that added the file, with the proper permissions, and the content exim expects to be there.
It seems that exim needs at least one local user, and that domain had all forwarding users.
Once I added a local user with a password, the errors stopped.

Hope this helps someone in the future.